# WordPress showing posts and limit

Tags: wordpress

i have very serious problem with displaying post in wordpress. I just want regular loop to limit for example on 5 posts per page and i want to show next and prev links (prev page and next page)

```
<?php $latest = new WP_Query('showposts=2'); ?>
<?php while( $latest->have_posts() ) : $latest->the_post(); ?>
<article class="blogArticle">
    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
    <h3><?php the_category(' '); ?></h3>
    <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
    <?php the_excerpt(); ?> 
</article> 
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: It's good form on StackOverflow to show what you've tried so far, but check out the first example here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts

Comment: my code from teplate file is   <?php $latest = new WP_Query('showposts=2'); ?>
<?php while( $latest->have_posts() ) : $latest->the_post(); ?>
<article class="blogArticle">
<h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
<h3><?php the_category(' '); ?></h3>
<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
</article>
<?php endwhile; ?>

Comment: If you look at the documentation, the correct argument is `posts_per_page` or `numberposts`

Comment: this is code that i picked up on google. how to use wp_query in mine idea / code? I checked link but its not becoming clear to me.

Comment: Any references I see to that parameter are ~5 years old or more, check the documentation link in my answer, just change the argument to `WP_Query` and it should show 5 posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To limit to 5 posts, you need to use the [`posts_per_page`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters) / [`numberposts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters) argument, not `showposts`. You can also just set Wordpress to show 5 posts by default and omit the `$paged` and `query_posts()` part.

```
<?php 
// You can omit this block by changing the number of posts on WP Admin > Settings > Reading > Blog pages show at most
// Used to control pagination
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
query_posts('posts_per_page=5&paged='.$paged);
// Omit above if you set the number of posts per page in WP Admin 
?>
<?php while( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<article class="blogArticle">
    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
    <h3><?php the_category(' '); ?></h3>
    <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
    <?php the_excerpt(); ?> 
</article> 
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

To handle the pagination you need to add calls to that [pagination functions](https://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination) outside your loop.

```
<?php next_posts_link('&laquo; Older Entries') ?>
<?php previous_posts_link('Newer Entries &raquo;') ?>
```

Comment: if u use that  `<?php $latest = new WP_Query('posts_per_page=3'); ?>
<?php while( $latest->have_posts() ) : $latest->the_post(); ?>
<article class="blogArticle">
    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
    <h3><?php the_category(' '); ?></h3>
    <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
    <?php the_excerpt(); ?> 
</article> 
<?php endwhile; ?> `   again same problem ? it shows 3 posts but i cant see next/prev text

Comment: That is different functionality, you will need to use the examples here https://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination

Comment: doublesharp thanks for your effort i add that code , it how prev link and it lead to page2 but it always show same posts :( and its not showing next link

Comment: can you use `query_posts()` instead of `WP_Query`? You need to reset the main `$wp_query`.

Comment: Right now i am very confused about ansers i just need code that will do following

 - list all posts from wordpress system
 - limit 5 posts per page
 - have featured image
 - have excerpt
 - have navigation PREV / NEXT PAGE at bottom.

its not really important what query to use i just need to this to work :)

Comment: I probably did something wrong :)  To be more specific i created homepage.php template and i use that code u sent me there. I setup in Settings -> Reading default page to be static page using homepage template. I copy your code and i get all posts limit doesnt work , no prev / next... i dont get it simple. Maybe i deleted something of function file etc , so i broken it.

Comment: Thanks you so much on solution! i just used index.php and its worked. Thanks